# Why does DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader change my table name from plural to singular?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbix-class

I'm using [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader) to create a schema like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader qw/make_schema_at/;

make_schema_at(
    "Mydb::Schema",
    {debug => 0, dump_directory => "../db/",
    generate_pod => 0,},
    ["dbi:mysql:mydb:localhost:3306", 'mydb', 'password'],
);
```

My table name in MySQL is `people`, but when I run this code, the generated class is named `Mydb::Schema::Result::Person`:

```
$ cat Mydb/Schema/Result/Person.pm 
use utf8;
package Mydb::Schema::Result::Person;

# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader
# DO NOT MODIFY THE FIRST PART OF THIS FILE

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'DBIx::Class::Core';
__PACKAGE__->table("people");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "pplid",
  {
    data_type => "smallint",
    extra => { unsigned => 1 },
    is_auto_increment => 1,
    is_nullable => 0,
  },
...
...
```

Why is "people" being converted to "Person"?

Comment: That's a script that you or someone else wrote. It's not part of DBIx::Class. You probably defined that mapping in there.

Comment: @simbabque All the script does is call `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::make_schema_at`. DBIx::Class is doing this, it's not some mapping that the OP created.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot the code wasn't in the question yet when I wrote that comment. I know about pluralization but I want expecting it to do it for words that cannot have a singular.

Comment: It's worth clarifying that DBIC **isn't** changing the name of your table. DBIC isn't doing anything to your database. DBIC is creating a resultset class which has a singular name based on your plural table name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader singularizes the names of Result classes. It makes sense to have a database table of people, but it doesn't make sense to have an object representing a single person called "People".

If you really want, you can change this by setting the [`naming`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::Base#naming) option in `make_schema_at`:

```
make_schema_at(
    "Mydb::Schema",
    {
        debug          => 0,
        dump_directory => "../db/",
        generate_pod   => 0,
        naming         => { monikers => 'preserve' }
    },
    ["dbi:mysql:mydb:localhost:3306", 'mydb', 'password'],
);
```

But I would recommend sticking with the defaults.

Comment: Thank you. Absolutely fixed the problem. Just one question: I hope it will not cause any trouble with rest of the DBIx code in my project?

Comment: another comment i would like to add is: when it changes name like that, it create a problem in keeping things straight in the programmer's head. Also it does not change the table name in the contents of .pm file, so I just used the option above and made it look 'normal'

Comment: With people and person it's weird, especially if English is not you first language, but it does make sense in general. Think _Books_ and _Book_, and it pretty reasonable.

Comment: @rajeev Keep in mind that objects of the generated class represent a *single row* in your database table, not the entire table. When you're fetching results from a list of people, a single result would be a person, not a people. And the whole point of an ORM is to abstract away the database, so you shouldn't really be thinking about the table names anyway.